# Como redirigir al usuario si el API te da un código 401 en Flutter

Tags: nodejs, api, flutter, dart

Tengo una pantalla principal, que muestra cinco registros de un usuario, para eso, tengo una función que hace la petición del usuario enviando un `userToken` y un `UserID` que me provee el servidor previamente y los guardo en `SharedPreferences`, pero el token, cuenta con tiempo de expiración, y necesito gestionar que si el token no está vigente (me devuelva un `error 401` o un mensaje como se ve en el código), lo envíe al login nuevamente (mostrando una alerta al usuario, que le notifique que debe iniciar sesión de nuevo) , pero el código no entra a esa parte y se va directamente a la excepción.

Anexo código de la función, agradeceré cualquier sugerencia o ayuda.

```
//HTTP Request
Future<List<Record>> fetchRecord() async {
  // final userid = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
  UserPreferences userPreferences = UserPreferences();
        //Consultas el dato almacenado y la asignas a la variable userId
  var userId = await userPreferences.getUserId();
  var userid = userId;
  var userToken = await userPreferences.getUserToken();
  var usertoken = userToken;
  var s = userid.toString() + '/' + usertoken.toString();
  print('esta es una prueba user' + s);
  //final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://e5ac-45-65-152-57.ngrok.io/get/fiverecords/1'));
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://f6a1-45-65-152-57.ngrok.io/get/fiverecords/$s'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>();

    return parsed.map<Record>((json) => Record.fromMap(json)).toList();
  } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
     showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    AlertDialog(
        title: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/error.png',
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ]),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: const [
              Text('Sesión expirada. \nInicie sesión. ')
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                sharedPreferences.clear(); //Para borrar T O D O.
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/LoginScreen'); 
              },
              child: const Text('Aceptar'))
        ]);
        throw new Exception('interno');

                  }
                  );
        throw Exception("Token is Expired"); // you may want to implement different exception class
      }
  throw Exception('Failed to load records.');
  }
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar como tienes declaradas las rutas en tu aplicación?

Comment: También siento que no es necesario que pongas el throw, porque ya estás mostrando un mensaje en pantalla

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación, lo resolví haciendo el ```Future<List<Record>> fetchRecord()``` a ```Future<dynamic> fetchRecord()``` y en lo sucesivos casos donde lo invoco, así que, tanto me cargan los datos como me muestra el mensaje cuando es necesario. Gracias.